# How to draw Composable Preview to HTML file

Tags: android, html, android-jetpack-compose

This is a general question, I'm looking for ideas. The goal is to write a documentation system.
So, I want to draw my Composable function on the HTML page.
What comes to my mind:

1. `@Preview` already draws it somehow but I'm not sure that it's easy to adapt it to HTML. At the first glance, I haven't found such possibility.
2. It's possible to draw the view on the emulator, take screenshot as Bitmap and upload this Bitmap. But this adds emulator dependency for generation which I'd like to avoid.

Perhaps, anyone has already worked on this problem? Appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to render Composables for android in HTML as compose is targeting JVM.

Depending on your use case [Compose for Web](https://compose-web.ui.pages.jetbrains.team/) might be helpful for you

For removing the emulator from your process you might prefer [Compose for Desktop](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-desktop/)